# Microsoft Azure VM IP change

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform

How can I change ephemeral IP of Microsoft Azure VM from shell/sdk?

I used "gcloud compute instances add/delete-access-config" for Google Cloud, is there anything similar for Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/reset-network-interface#use-azure-powershell-1) on how to use Azure PowerShell to reset network interface:

1.Make sure that you have the latest Azure PowerShell installed.

2.Open an elevated Azure PowerShell session (Run as administrator). Run the following commands:

```
#Set the variables 
$SubscriptionID = "<Subscription ID>"​
$VM = "<VM Name>"
$CloudService = "<Cloud Service>"
$VNET = "<Virtual Network>"
$IP = "NEWIP"

#Log in to the subscription​ 
Add-AzureAccount
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId 

#Check whether the new IP address is available in the virtual network.
Test-AzureStaticVNetIP –VNetName $VNET –IPAddress  $IP

#Add/Change static IP. This process will not change MAC address
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $CloudService -Name $VM | Set-AzureStaticVNetIP -IPAddress $IP |Update-AzureVM
```

3.Try to RDP to your machine. If successful, you can change the Private IP address back to the original if you would like. Otherwise, you can keep it.

Answer (score 0):

First, there are two IPs for the VM: public IP and private IP. But you also need to know that all the public IP addresses are assigned by Azure and you cannot set for a special one. For the private IP, you can set with a special one in the subnet which does not in use.

No matter the private IP or the public IP, all they are associated with the NIC, so if you want to change the public IP, you'd better create a new public IP with the static method and associate it to the NIC of the VM.

Find the VM NIC information:

```
nic_id=$(az vm show -g groupName -n vmName -d --query networkProfile.networkInterfaces[0].id)
az network nic show --ids $nic_id
```

Update the public IP, I assume you already created a new public IP:

```
az network nic ip-config update -g groupName --nic-name nicName -n ipconfigurationName --public-ip-address publicIpName
```

If you want to change the private IP, just use the parameter `--private-ip-address` like this:

```
az network nic ip-config update -g groupName --nic-name nicName -n ipconfigurationName --private-ip-address privateIpAddress
```

You can get more details about the Azure CLI command `az network nic ip-config update` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/nic/ip-config?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-nic-ip-config-update).